# Grabbing the time stamp in a csv using Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a csv that I want to read into a pandas dataframe and analyze. One column is called 'Date', and can be easily turned into a datetime type using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, format='%Y%m%d')
```

However that column doesn't contain the time associated with the row. The time (for some unknown reason) is contained within a string in another column, equivalent to a 'comment' column. A sample entry in the 'comment' column looks similar to the following string:

```
'Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123A12 Term:AABBC'
```

I want to extract the time before the word 'Transactie', which in this case is 21:58. Is that possible to do in pandas, or do I need to a more general regex package?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [pandas string manipulation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/api.html#string-handling) `pd.Series.str` vector functions. For example,

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["20160519", "20160519"], 
"Datum": ['Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123A12 Term:AABBC', 
          'Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 22:58 Transactie:123A12 Term:AABBC']})

In[2]: df.Datum.astype(str).str.split(pat=' ', expand=True)[2]
Out[2]: 
0    21:58
1    22:58
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that pandas lets you apply any function along a column! I find myself often doing `.apply(lambda x: function(x))` [Here is a relevant example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#row-or-column-wise-function-application) from the pandas documentation.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
def datum_to_datetime(row):
    time = row['Datum'].split()[-3]

    return time

df.apply(datum_to_datetime)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but that doesn't answer my question. I want to get the clock time contained within the string, not convert the 'Date' column into a datetime object.

Comment: great -- you can pass ANY function. If you apply along the full dataframe, instead of just a column, you can do operations across multiple columns. see my edits -- if you update your original question with the two columns of interest that might help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) or [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by arbitrary whitespace `\s+`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Datum': ['Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123A12 Term:AABBC',
                            'Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123A12 Term:AABBC']})

print (df)
                                               Datum
0  Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123...
1  Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123...

df['Time'] = df.Datum.str.extract(r'([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d)', expand=True)

print (df)
                                               Datum   Time
0  Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123...  21:58
1  Passnumber:123 19-05-2016 21:58 Transactie:123...  21:58

print (df.Datum.str.split(r'\s+', expand=True)[2])
0    21:58
1    21:58
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Test [regex](https://regex101.com/r/eN9lV6/1).

It seems `extract` method is the fastest:

```
In [408]: %timeit (df.Datum.str.extract(r'([0-2]\d:[0-5]\d)', expand=True))
The slowest run took 4.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 347 µs per loop

In [409]: %timeit (df.Datum.str.split(r'\s+', expand=True)[2])
The slowest run took 4.63 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 675 µs per loop

In [410]: %timeit (df.Datum.astype(str).str.split(pat=' ', expand=True)[2])
The slowest run took 4.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 727 µs per loop
```